# Removing spam subdomains from Google index

Tags: seo, google-search, google-search-console

If I do a google search using "site:mydomain.com" (mydomain isn't mine obviously!) I get a lot of first and 2nd page results which contain bogus subdomains.

First of all, WTF? 
Why would anyone setup links to create a Google index with a bogus subdomain for my website?
Whats the scam here? I've had a significant drop in google ranking over the last 3 months and I can't work out why.

A sample of these subdomains:
    w.
    w3ww.
    www.lawsuitsettlementamounts.com2960.
    www.lawsuitsettlementamounts.com4519.
    www.lawsuitsettlementamounts.com3754.
    beft.ru5258.
    wa-go2ui.com10992.
    wa-go2ui.com10993.

I've updated apache2's siteavailable file for the domain to disallow wild card sub domains.
So now anything other than the domain or www. is allowed. (As per what I've told google via webmaster).
These bogus links now return 403

Is this enough?
Should I do more?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit more research I think the best response is a 404 "Page not found".
So I've updated my apache configs for sites-enable/000-default to contain the following:

EDIT - I've changed this from 404 to 400. I think 404 is not a strong enough message to the search engines that the subdomain is bogus. "syntactically incorrect" (400) is probably more accurate than "page not found" (404)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bogus
Redirect 400 /
</VirtualHost>
```